# Rsync a directory from a local server to a remote server without losing permissions

Tags: linux, centos, rsync, file-transfer

I need to transfer a directory from my local server to a remote server on the exact same place on the remote server. In the directory, there are a lot of different users involved and I want to preserve those.

What command do I have to use then and will Rsync be the smartest option.

For reference, the dir is `/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/`

Answer (score 6):

Rsync has the `-a` or `achive` option that will maintain permissions for you as well as a few other things. To just maintain permissions, use `-p`. Read the man page for rsync and it explains it all.

Comment: Plus one for RTFM